# Continuous vs. Line Spectra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, thermal-radiation

A hot solid or liquid produces a continuous emission spectrum while a hot rarefied gas produces a discrete emission spectrum. (And a hot dense gas produces a continuous spectrum with absorption lines?) What microscopic property is it about these various states and densities that lead to the formation of continuous or line spectra?

Comment: Quantization of energy levels/bands of electrons in the atoms/molecules. It doesn't logo like you researched the question before asking.

Comment: Can’t a rarefied gas be composed of molecules with bands of energy rather than quantized energy levels?

Comment: No. Energy bands only occur in close-packed crystals when the inter-species distance is within 1 order of magnitude of the species radii, due to orbital overlap. This cannot by definition occur in gases,let alone rarefied gases.